# Java Regex all non word characters except whitespace

Tags: java, regex

This has Probably been asked before, but i want to split a string at every non word character except the white space in java. i do not have experience with regex in general and the wiki doesn't really help.

I've tried it with this: `"[\\W][^\\s]"` but that did not help.

**Edit**: how the String is read out of the file

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.answers));

        try
        {
            while (sc.hasNext())
            {
                sb.append(sc.next());
            }
        } finally
        {
            sc.close();
        }
```

Comment: It was asked. `[^\\w\\s]+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split using this regex:

```
String[] tok = input.split( "[\\W&&\\S]+" );
```

This will split on any non-word that is also a non-space character hence leaving aside space characters for split.

Check **Character classes** in [Java Pattern reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex did removes the space characters

Comment: My mistake, it looks, like the space was cut off, while reading the text from  the file.

Comment: Thanks, i have added the code in my question. P.s. the files will be only 2 lines long, so performance doesn't really matter

Comment: You can use [Files.readAllBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) to read full file into a byte array and then convert byte array to string.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution for java 6? I'm using Android Api 15, which doesn't support java 7

Comment: Nevermind, just changing the scanner to `Scanner sc = new Scanner(...).useDelimiter("");` worked

Comment: Yes indeed I also used `String data = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();` on Java 6.